# Makemigrations Django TypeError missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, database-migration

When i run makemigrations in django i got the error :

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

[image: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument]

and this is my code :

```
from django.db import models


class List(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return "List:{}".format(self.name)


class Card(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name="cards")
    story_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    business_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Card:{}".format(self.title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field `on_delete` is required parameter. So you have to define `list` with it

```
list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name="cards", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the class to which the model is related and the on_delete option.

Comment: It's worth adding that specifying `on_delete` is required since Django 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

the error message points to a missing argument in the field `list` of the model `Card`. Try something like `list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name="cards", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`